# Не отображаются компоненты в toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

После добавления navigation drawer, не отображаются фрагменты в тулбаре.

вот layout/menu

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Код в активити :

```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

          @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.logout) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

код в фрагменте :

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(searchQueryListener);

    }
```

Comment: Может в активити надо супер возвращать при создании меню? И посмотрите по истории коммитов что вы поменяли при добавлении дровера - сразу станет ясно что сломалось

Comment: Возвращал super, все ровно не отображает. Смотрел по комитах, не могу найти...

Comment: У вас, получается два тулара? Один в актвити другой во фрагменте? Должен быть тоько один - в актвити

Comment: Я хотел дополнить тот что в фрагменте, там используется тот же тутбар

Comment: Во фрагменте у вас другой тулбар. Вы его в разметке фрагмента находите и назначаете его вместо тулбара актвити. В итоге у вас ничего не должно бы работать и на экране должно быть два тулбара.

Comment: Удалил его, но проблема все ровно остается, в  тулбаре ничего нет кроме navigation drawer

Comment: Приведите в вопросе нынешнее состояние кода. Добавьте подробностей. Пока что слишком мало инфы и можно гадать неделями что у вас не так

Comment: Посмотрите, я обновил

Comment: У вас что-то не то в `onCreateOptionsMenu` - кажетс последние три строки там лишние, а последняя вообще неправильная ибо не тот метод вызывается

Comment: Последнюю поменял по вашему совету в первом коментарие. Наверное не правильно понял. Уже заработало, огромное спасибо.

Comment: Подскажите еще, как в фрагменте скрыть navigation drawer ?

Comment: Написал в ответ. А скрыть можно по разному. Например создайте в активити метод делающий это, в фрагменте через `((ИМЯ_ВАШЕЙ_АКТИВИТИ)getActivity()).ВАШ_МЕТОД_В_АКТИВИТИ();` можно этот метод вызвать

Comment: Можна более поподробней. Я сделал так  ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onNavigationItemSelected(); Но что передать ему в параметр, и как его скрьть ?

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос. Кратко - в актвити надо метод с кодом `drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);` и этот метод надо вызывать из фрагмнета как раз описанным вами способом

Comment: И не забудьте принять ответ на этот вопрос. И про правило не забывайте - один вопрос - один вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неправильный метод использовался для возврата значения из метода создания меню в активити

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    //а должно быть 
    //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```